# Scrapy+Splash returning wrong headers

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

When using Splash with Scrapy the headers are returned from the Splash server instead of the website Splash renders.

`response.headers` returns:

```
{b'Server': [b'TwistedWeb/19.7.0'], b'Date': [b'Sun, 11 Jul 2021 07:31:32 GMT'], b'Content-Type': [b'text/html; charset=utf-8']}
```

And I'm trying to get the headers of the actual website:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 11 Jul 2021 07:05:49 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache
X-Cache: HIT
```

How can I get the headers of the website instead of the Splash server?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

```
splash_lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(0.5))

    local entries = splash:history()
    local last_response = entries[#entries].response

    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        headers = last_response.headers
    }
end
"""
```

And then refer it to `response.headers` with Scrapy.